# I have a json value in database ["20200"] in this format

Tags: c#, winforms

,i need just 20200 value, how can I take this value? when try to take to a string its return a value like "[\"20200"]"

Comment: Take a look at Newtonsoft Json or any other json library. The other option would be to parse it manually but that's not clean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The squared brackets denote an array of values. You can use a JSON serialization library like [NewtonSoft JSON](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) to deserialize the data into an `IEnumerable<string>` and then take the first value:

```
var v = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<string>>("[\"20200\"]").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried this but how can I use that value in my next line. Can you give little more explanations?

Comment: @Mulwaffer just store the result in a variable. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I have one more doubt , If we have two elements in json, can i use same thing?

Comment: @Mulwaffer: yes, JsonConvert will deserialize the array. In case you have several items, you just omit the `.FirstOrDefault()`. Then you can use the `IEnumerable<string>` that contains all items.